# Preventing searches in subfolders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search, search-results, subfolders

How can I prevent subfolders from document libraries appearing in search results in SharePoint online?

I can currently prevent searches and indexing on documents in a document library but I need it to prevent in subfolders rather than the entire document library.

Comment: You can add certain specific crawl rules and restrict crawler to exclude those items from crawl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for - http://blog.cognit.se/sharepoint-search-how-to-filter-out-folders/

I would probably modify the appropriate search verticals and result sources to include the ContentTypeID exclusion for the Folder content type.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I don't see these options to edit the search functionality. I have several subfolders but a archive folder in every subfolder that i need hidden from search results.

Comment: Okay, well, in that case you can't exclude by Content Type ID so you're going to have to create a custom Result Source that excludes any folder with that name, or you could try looking at Result Removal, but then you have to explicitly define the URL to each folder I think.

Comment: So, I cant define a parameter that excludes all folders with "Archive" and any files in it?

Comment: Not in such a simple way, no, not to my knowledge. As I said you can use a custom result source that says 'exclude folders called Archive' and point your searches at that, or just manually enter the Archive URLs for Search Result Removal.

Comment: There has to be a better way to do this. You would think this would be a common request. The settings allow it for document libraries. What up microsoft?!

Comment: To be fair what you're asking is pretty specific - not just hide folders, not hide things of a given name, but both. The way your system works I'm struggling to think of anything unique to identify what you want excluded as it's going to be quite varied.
You could always try creating a new content type of the Folder type and make all the Archive type folders that CT, then exclude by Content Type ID... but that would be predicated on users always using the right CT.